# Можно ли в C# задать метод, который на вход будет принимать разные перечисления (enum)?

Tags: c#, generics, enum

Имеется несколько перечислений. 
Есть метод, который принимает в качестве аргумента словарь, одним из типов которого является перечислимый тип. Можно ли как-то обобщённо реализовать метод 1 раз вместо перегрузок под каждое перечисление?

Сейчас всё реализовано следующим образом:

```
public enum URStatus { planned, watching, completed, on_hold, dropped, rewatching = 9 }
public enum AKind { tv, tv_13, tv_24, tv_48, movie, ova, ona, special }
public enum Duration { S, D, F }
public enum Order { ranked, popularity, name, aired_on, id }
public enum Rating { g, pg, pg_13, r, r_plus, rx }
public enum TitleStatus { released, latest, ongoing, anons }
//...
public class Search
{
    //...
    public IDictionary<URStatus, bool> mylist { get; set; }
    public IDictionary<AKind, bool> type { get; set; }
    public IDictionary<Duration, bool> duration { get; set; }
    public IDictionary<Order, bool> order { get; set; }
    public IDictionary<Rating, bool> rating { get; set; }
    public IDictionary<TitleStatus, bool> status { get; set; }
    //...
    private string DictToStr(IDictionary<URStatus, bool> filter)
    {
        var str = "";
        foreach (var item in filter)
        {
            str += (item.Value) ? "" : "!";
            str += (int)item.Key + ","; //явное преобразование невозможно для обобщённого типа
        }                              //плюс ко всему, числовые значения нужны только для enum URStatus.
        return str;
    }

    private string DictToStr<T>(IDictionary<T, bool> filter)
    {
        var str = "";
        foreach (var item in filter)
        {
            str += (item.Value) ? "" : "!";
            str += item.Key + ",";
        }
        return str;
    }
}
```

Можно ли перегруженный метод для URStatus как-то тоже включить в обощённый метод?
То есть, добавить проверку в методе именно на этот enum и если он, то возвращать число, а не строку

Comment: так и сделай generic метод `private string DictToStr<EnumType>(IDictionary<EnumType, bool> filter)`

Comment: @Grundy, вначале пытался и столкнулся с какой-то проблемой.. после вашего совета попробовал ещё раз и заработало.. спасибо.. голова походу уже не соображает)

Comment: @Grundy, а можно как то модернизировать тело, чтобы для отдельного перечисления он брал число, а не название параметра, как в моём примере.. что-то вроде, "Если EnumType это Duration, то:  `str += (int)item.Key + ",";` - обычный способ получения числа из enum тут не сработает, ибо функция воспринимает EnumType как любой тип, а не исключительно перечислимый, а значит и явное преобразование не работает..

Comment: а в текущем варианте он название выводит?

Comment: @Grundy, да.. в текущем варианте он парсится в строку, а enum при парсинге в строку возвращает имя перечисления.

Comment: @Grundy внёс изменения в вопрос..

Comment: можно использовать класс Convert: `Convert.ToInt32(item.Key)`

Comment: @Grundy, а как понять, что входной параметр нужного перечисления и надо конвертировать в число?

Comment: @Mr.Modest, typeof(EnumType)

Comment: @VadimProkopchuk, спасибо. помогло) `if (typeof(T) == URStatus.planned.GetType()) { }`

Comment: @Mr.Modest а почему бы не использовать `if (typeof(t) == typeof(URStatus))` или чет не правильно понял

Comment: @VadimProkopchuk, скорее всего вы все правильно поняли. Это я затупил на моменте, когда не нашёл в URStatus GetType().. спасибо за совет, переделаю. Ваш вариант куда эстетичнее и правильнее)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Спасибо @Grundy и @VadimProkopchuk

```
public enum URStatus { planned, watching, completed, on_hold, dropped, rewatching = 9 }
public enum AKind { tv, tv_13, tv_24, tv_48, movie, ova, ona, special }
public enum Duration { S, D, F }
public enum Order { ranked, popularity, name, aired_on, id }
public enum Rating { g, pg, pg_13, r, r_plus, rx }
public enum TitleStatus { released, latest, ongoing, anons }
//...
public class Search
{
    //...
    public IDictionary<URStatus, bool> mylist { get; set; }
    public IDictionary<AKind, bool> type { get; set; }
    public IDictionary<Duration, bool> duration { get; set; }
    public IDictionary<Order, bool> order { get; set; }
    public IDictionary<Rating, bool> rating { get; set; }
    public IDictionary<TitleStatus, bool> status { get; set; }
    //...
    private string DictToStr<T>(IDictionary<T, bool> filter)
    {
        var str = "";
        foreach (var item in filter)
        {
            str += (item.Value) ? "" : "!";

            if (typeof(T) == typeof(URStatus)) //Если filter = mylist
            {
                str += Convert.ToInt32(item.Key) + ",";
            }
            else //в остальных случаях
            {
                str += item.Key + ",";
            }
        }
        return str;
    }
}
```